# Having some trouble reading JSON response

Tags: servlets, request, response, extjs4.1

I make an ajax request to the servlet that returns the result of a database query.
I can see with firebug the response and I want to put these results in a list (or other..) that I have already created.

I tried to read [this post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?168602-Newbie-Having-trouble-getting-ExtJS-v4-to-read-JSON-Array) but it didn't help me..

Code:

this is the ajax request:

```
                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: '/VIProject/Container',

                        success: function (action){alert('Lista caricata!'); console.debug(action); },
                        failure: function (){alert('Errore nel caricamento...');},
                        headers: {
                            'my-header': 'foo'
                        },
                        params: { action: "GETCONTAINERLIST" }
                    });
```

response from servlet(firebug):

```
{"message":"OK","container":[{"idOrdine":"1","numLotto":"123"},{"idOrdine":"2","numLotto":"321"},{"idOrdine":"3","numLotto":"876"}],"success":true}
```

list:

```
    var listView = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    width:425,
    height:250,
    id: 'lista',
    collapsible:true,
    title:'Simple ListView <i>(0 items selected)</i>',
    store: //???
    multiSelect: true,
    viewConfig: {
        emptyText: 'No images to display'
    },

    columns: [{
        text: 'idOrdine',
        flex: 15,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'idOrdine'
    },{
        text: 'Last Modified',
        flex: 20,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'numLotto'
    }]
});
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code to use a store:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['idOrdine', 'numLotto']
})

var listView = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    width:425,
    height:250,
    id: 'lista',
    collapsible:true,
    title:'Simple ListView <i>(0 items selected)</i>',
    store: store: {
        model: MyModel,
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/VIProject/Container',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'container'
            }
        }
    },
    multiSelect: true,
    viewConfig: {
        emptyText: 'No images to display'
    },

    columns: [{
        text: 'idOrdine',
        flex: 15,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'idOrdine'
    },{
        text: 'Last Modified',
        flex: 20,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'numLotto'
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried with your code but nothing happens. My list is empty.. :s i have a response from the servlet but i can't use this data .. help!

Comment: You'll need to post more information. Does it make a request to the server? Also, in your code you never render the grid. Are you doing that somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Even in this way it works:

```
        var proxy=new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url:'/VIProject/Container'});

    var reader=new Ext.data.JsonReader({},[
          {name: 'idOrdine', mapping: 'idOrdine'},
          {name: 'numLotto', mapping: 'numLotto'}
     ]);

     var store=new Ext.data.Store(    {
         proxy:proxy,
         reader:reader
     });

    store.load();
```

I tried in every way.. but i don't know what to do!